# Getting count of records on the basis if datetime column in table for certain period of time

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I have one table called Forms where we are storing multiple rows.
Forms table has columns `FormId(uniqueidentifier),FormName(varchar(max)),SubmitedDate(datetime),HasValidFields(bit),IsValidRecord(bit)`.
I am using entity framework 6. 
Using api user can query records on the basis of last 24 hrs, last 7 days , last 30 days or last 12 Months.
For different query I have return number of Valid records by reading the value of column `IsValidRecord(bit)` for those requested days/months 
and for each query I have to return number of records which has **HasValidFields** using column `HasValidFields(bit)`.

**As there will be many records in this table, So to improve perfomance which would be the suitable method?
Shall I just query using EF or shall we use view , or use indexing?**
Record table :

```
 FormId                               FormName  SubmitedDate    HasValidFields  IsValidRecord
F3999F60-57B4-494C-868F-331EE5DC6A5F    Form1   10/4/16 11:51   1                 1
9C23FFC0-F5C9-4E52-B272-34F75D8B4EE6    Form13  10/4/16 11:51   0                 1
0658B103-D7B5-4C9E-8209-7BAB82C0E35E    Form12  10/4/16 11:51   1                 1
2C348300-7FD2-471E-8DA4-D7E0DD4B53EE    Form18  10/4/16 11:51   1                 0
F3999F60-57B4-494C-868F-331EE5DC6A5F    Form13  10/5/16 5:24    1                 0
0664C797-0CDF-443C-8ABE-E497E72BE738    Form19  10/5/16 5:24    1                 1
F3999F60-57B4-494C-868F-331EE5DC6A5F    Form12  10/5/16 5:24    0                 1
9C23FFC0-F5C9-4E52-B272-34F75D8B4EE6    Form15  10/5/16 5:24    0                 1
DAF34CEB-F7F6-4386-829C-D0D76E4E657D    Form16  10/5/16 5:43    1                 1
9C23FFC0-F5C9-4E52-B272-34F75D8B4EE6    Form17  10/5/16 5:43    1                 1
```

Sample output for last 7 days (Not on basis of above sample input)

**Date**              **ValidRecords**

27-Oct-16                  12

26-Oct-16                  40

25-Oct-16                  12

24-Oct-16                  41

23-Oct-16                  19

22-Oct-16                  46

21-Oct-16                  56

For last hours it will hours column instead of date and for Years its will be years column.

Comment: Sample output data does not help if we don't see what the starting data was.

Comment: *which would be the suitable method* I don't know. For one, we don't know your current method and performance. Asking for *the suitable method* is far too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an index on SubmittedDate and HasValidFields (ie one index that uses both columns).

I don't think that Entity Framework generates indexes for you, although you can add indexes with entity framework using attributes (if doing code first design).